# Console Application Fiddler

Tags: fiddler

I am trying to connect my console application to Fiddler. I use .NET 7. I am unable to see any request and responses. Here is what I see:

[image]

Here is what I tried:

1. Go to myapp.ConsoleClient.exe.config. Add:

```xml
 <system.net>
 <defaultProxy>
  <proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="false" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="false" />
 </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

2. Opened Fiddler. Then, open Visual Studio. Start console app.
3. Entered `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` in the CMD.

I receive an error that SSL requests are failing. Let me know what I am missing.

Comment: As you have manually configured your app to use Fiddler I would first disable "Act as system proxy at startup" and restart Fiddler. That eliminates requests from other programs like Teams as shown in your screenshot. The command you use `dotnet dev-certs` is for local web app development, so the command-line application is a web server? Because otherwise I don't see how the command should fit in. And finally please tell us about your application which HTTPS requests fail, are they generated by your code or a library (a library may use certificate pinning).

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I am using the Fika Amazon API library https://github.com/abuzuhri/Amazon-SP-API-CSharp/blob/main/Source/FikaAmazonAPI.SampleCode/FeedsSample.cs. I am using a C# console application.